# Cannot start jupyter notebook when i type the address in the browser

Tags: python-3.x, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I downloaded a docker image for cadquery and jupyter notebook.

When i run the container, it gave me this message:

```
[I 19:48:59.700 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /opt/conda/envs/cq/share/jupyter/lab
[I 19:48:59.703 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/cq
[I 19:48:59.703 LabApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.1 is running at:
[I 19:48:59.703 LabApp] http://58bb309866f3:8888/
[I 19:48:59.703 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

When i visit `http://58bb309866f3:8888/` in my browser (docker-host machine) i get: `This site can’t be reached`.

So how am i able to start jupyter? I have never used jupyter before - i don't clearly know what that is - but it is the way to get access to cadquery's API.

EDIT:
I started the docker container with :

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -v $WORKDIR:/home/cq -p 8888:8888 bwalter42/jupyter_cadquery:1.0.0
```

Comment: What command did you use to start the container? It is probably something like `docker run .... -p aportNumber:8888 ..... imageName ` . If that is the case then you can reach the Jupiter at localhost:aportNumber  . The address  `58bb309866f3:8888` is an internal container address in that cannot be reached from the host

Comment: @camba1 sudo docker run -it --rm -v $WORKDIR:/home/cq -p 8888:8888 bwalter42/jupyter_cadquery:1.0.0

Comment: you should be able to connect to Jupiter on localhost:8888 in that case. Also just found the relevant documentation here: https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: @camba1 it worked! Thank you very much my friend. Please make a proper answer so i can upvote and mark it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address `58bb309866f3:8888` is an internal container address in that cannot be reached from the host

You should connect using localhost and the port mapped in your docker run command. In this case you can connect using `localhost:8888`